Overlaying Text Boxes on Scroll using JavaScript?
I'm creating a website that shows a grid of black rectangles on HTML, and I want text boxes to appear when the user scrolls that appear above the rectangles and remain there for some time for the user to read, similar to here: https://mkorostoff.github.io/1-pixel-wealth/.
I've tried to do this with a combination of HTML and JS but have been unsuccessful so far, as the text boxes aren't appearing on the screen.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const gridContainer = document.getElementById('grid');
  const infoBoxes = [{
    title: 'Information Box 1',
    content: 'This is some information about the conflict.'
  }, {
    title: 'Information Box 2',
    content: 'More details and statistics.'
  }, {
    title: 'Information Box 3',
    content: 'Additional context and historical background.'
  }];

  const totalRectangles = 3000; // Total number of rectangles (example value)
  const scrollThreshold = 100; // Number of rectangles to scroll past before showing the next info box
  const stickyDuration = 400; // Number of pixels the info box should remain sticky
  let currentInfoBoxIndex = -1;
  let currentInfoBox = null;

  for (let i = 0; i < totalRectangles; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement('div');
    square.classList.add('grid-item');
    gridContainer.appendChild(square);
  }

  // Function to check if an element is in viewport
  function isElementInViewport(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.left >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  }

  // Function to handle scroll event
  function handleScroll() {
    const scrollPosition = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
    const rectanglesScrolled = Math.floor(scrollPosition / 200); // Assuming each rectangle height is 200px
    console.log("rectangles", rectanglesScrolled)
    // Determine which info box to show based on scroll position
    const infoBoxIndex = Math.floor(rectanglesScrolled / scrollThreshold);

    if (infoBoxIndex !== currentInfoBoxIndex) {
      // Remove the current info box if it exists
      if (currentInfoBox) {
        currentInfoBox.classList.remove('visible', 'sticky');
      }

      // Add the new info box if it exists in the array
      if (infoBoxIndex < infoBoxes.length) {
        currentInfoBoxIndex = infoBoxIndex;
        currentInfoBox = document.querySelectorAll('.info-box')[infoBoxIndex];
        console.log(currentInfoBox)
        currentInfoBox.classList.add('visible', 'sticky');
      } else {
        currentInfoBoxIndex = -1;
        currentInfoBox = null;
      }
    }

    // Remove the sticky class after the sticky duration
    if (currentInfoBox) {
      const infoBoxRect = currentInfoBox.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (infoBoxRect.top < 20 || infoBoxRect.bottom > stickyDuration) {
        currentInfoBox.classList.remove('sticky');
      }
    }
  }

  // Listen for scroll events
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

  // Initial check in case some boxes are already in view
  handleScroll();
});
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>A Factful Representation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent horizontal scrolling */
        }

        .content {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr)); /* Adjust the size of the squares */
            gap: 100px; /* Adjust the spacing between squares */
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 2000px; /* Adjust the max width */
            margin: 2px auto;
            border-width: 2px;
            border-color: red;
        }

        .grid-item {
            width: 100px;  /* New size */
            height: 200px; /* New size */
            background-color: black;
        }

        .info-box {
            position: absolute; /* Absolute positioning */
            width: 90%;
            left: 50%; /* Center horizontally */
            transform: translateX(-50%); /* Center horizontally */
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #f8f9fa;
            border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            opacity: 0; /* Initially hidden */
            transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out, transform 0.6s ease-out;
        }

        .info-box.visible {
            opacity: 1; /* Fully visible */
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0); /* Positioned normally */
        }

        .info-box.sticky {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            top: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container content" id="container">
        <h1 class="my-4 text-center">A Factful Representation of The Conflict in Gaza</h1>
        <p class="text-center">Data from the <a href="https://www.ochaopt.org/">UN Office for the Coordination of Humanitarian Affairs (OCHA)</a></p>
        
        <div><p class="text-center"><i>Scroll down</i></p></div>
        <br><br>
        <div id="grid" class="grid-container"></div>
        <div id="info-boxes-container">
            <!-- Information Box 1 -->
            <div class="info-box" id="info-box-1">
                <h3>Information Box 1</h3>
                <p>This is some information about the conflict.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Information Box 2 -->
            <div class="info-box" id="info-box-2">
                <h3>Information Box 2</h3>
                <p>More details and statistics.</p>
                <div class="chart-container">
                    <div class="chart-wrapper">
                        <canvas id="exampleChart1" class="chart"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Information Box 3 -->
            <div class="info-box" id="info-box-3">
                <h3>Information Box 3</h3>
                <p>Additional context and historical background.</p>
                <div class="chart-container">
                    <div class="chart-wrapper">
                        <canvas id="exampleChart2" class="chart"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Add more boxes as needed -->
        </div>
        
    </div>




I placed your code in to a snippet to try and create a working example, however there's error because you didn't include the .info-box elements. Can you please update the question to include all relevant HTML

@RoryMcCrossan should be fixed now
